# mysql Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

am new to mysql and typeorm and  am trying to get all the posts belonging to a specific user and i want to use the id for this operation but am getting `Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`.

this is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { createQueryBuilder } from 'typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm/repository/Repository';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
 
  async userPosts(id): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.posts', 'post')
      .where('user.id = :id', { id: id }) // whats the problem here ?
      .getOne();
  }
 
}
```

and thats my user entity

```
import { Post } from 'src/post/post.entity';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Post, (post: Post) => post.user, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  posts: Post[];
}
```

Comment: I request you to share CREATE statements of a table `user` and `posts`

Answer (score -1):

{ id: id }
You don't specify which table the id field is coming from. Did you mean:
{ user.id: id }

Comment: This shall not be a problem